# Batch file 'type >>' How to create a new line?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

Batch file `type >>` How to create a new line?

```
type "C:\AutoFrameworkResults\LogFiles\logFileSystemTime.txt" >> "\\xxx.1xx.1.xx\AutoFrameworkResults\log.txt"
```

for example:

```
Text1 Text2 Text3
```

Would become:

```
Text1

Text2

Text3
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want to achieve here. Do you want to replace spaces in the content of a source file with newlines? Multiple newlines? Batch or PowerShell?

Answer (score 0):

Using *PowerShell* (since you have added the tag): You could try to replace every whitespace characters with a newline:

```
(Get-Content "C:\AutoFrameworkResults\LogFiles\logFileSystemTime.txt" -raw) -replace '\s+', [System.Environment]::NewLine >> "\\xxx.1xx.1.xx\AutoFrameworkResults\log.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume, based on the paths in your example, that you are using a DOS/Windows environment.

One solution would be to use **awk** or **sed**.
These are originally unix tools, but they have been ported to DOS / Windows environments.  You could google it to find out, but make sure you install or copy the executables from a trustworthy source.

I have used small unix-like executables on Windows cmd line, from Cygnus tools (Cygwin) before, and they are trustworthy.

You would use the tools to detect spaces in your input file and replace them with some kind of newline / carriage return.  Note that Windows uses a different style of newline / carriage return than unix / linux does.